# Help Seldon choose between four doors

Tags: situation

Q . It is a fourth avenue of new jersey. It contained a scary house .

One day a fellow  named Seldon who is 7 feet tall standing with his friends talking about scary house . Seldon know all about the scary house which is 10 feet height. His friends forced him to step into scary house . Seldon with no alternate entered into the room , all the doors were closed.

He started walking in darkness, he tried switching on the switches on the switch board, unfortunately, no lights ON due to power cut(i.e he is in completey dark room ).House contains 3 doors (Door number  B4 , B9 , B16, B25).

Door number-B9   contain a long pit with 'x' feet height (where `x` is 400)

Doom number B16  contain an electric chair which will kill the person.

Condition: He should sit in chair compulsory if he chose B16.

Room number-B25  contain an acid pool and slow humming noise is being heard by him from B25 ( I think it's radio with unsynced frequency in it ).

How can  he escape from house ?

Comment: Is the "House contains 3 doors" a typo? There is 4 according to description.

Comment: Why say 'x' feet high and not just 400 feet high?

Comment: Electric chair won't kill if there's no power :-/

Comment: A little more attention to grammar and formatting would help...

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a bit of a trick here, but...

> OP only describes 3 doors, because the 4th door, B4, is the one that Seldon entered from. Not sure if it important to note the heights of items listed, or the fact that door numbers are perfect squares... because whichever door he tries, he may survive or not, but not ESCAPE. To escape all he needs to do is go back to door B4 and get the heck out the way he came in.

Answer (score 0):

He opens the doors from which no humming noise coming out (Eliminating the chance of getting fallen into the acid pool - B25).

As he opens the door, he checks with his leg if it has floor. It won't if it's the room with 400-meter pit (B9).

If it has floor, it will be either the room with the electric chair or safe room. He checks if the room contains the electric chair, it will be safe since there is no electricity in the house (B-16).

If there is no electric chair, he is in the safe door (B4) or go to the remaining door (B4). If that is the Goal of OP.

Answer (score 0):

He should go out door

> B16

Because

> There is no power in the house, so the electric chair will not function, leading to his escape.